# Ubuntu reboots on its on in recovery mode

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, virtualbox, lvm

I have an issue with Ubuntu server rebooting on its own while in recovery mode. It's running in VirtualBox and I want to prepare in order to shrink the `.vdi` file.

The interesting thing is, when I boot into recovery mode, I can enter my root password and let it sit there at that screen fine. I can also type random keys and be fine. However if I start typing

```
mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext4 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

that’s when it will reboot on its own and take me back to the screen with the options on it.

What I am trying to do is use zerofree. I have gotten past that mounting part a few times and far enough to run the

```
zerofree -v /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

but in about 5 to 20 seconds it will randomly reboot on its own.

I have looked at syslog, but nothing jumps out at me. Then again I am not real sure what I am looking for either.

This is Ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: Why do you want to run zerofree? Maybe there is a alternative.

Comment: @sudodus I am looking to zero out the free space so I can shrink the VDI file. This is in a virtual box. But I am not sure if the zerofree is the issue as it will reboot before I get to that command. But if there is a way to zero out the freespace I`ll try it. Then after I could use the VBoxmanage modifyhd --compact command to shrink the VDI

Comment: I see. So you use LVM in a virtual machine. Maybe you need special tools for this operation to work well with LVM. Without LVM (but still in VirtualBox) it works to use this command line with the dangerous dd: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/target/blank bs=4096` where `/mnt/target` is the mount point of the target partition, that you want to 'zerofree'. Maybe it works with LVM too, maybe not.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, and have the same problem. But it reboots after I login, even if I do nothing, just log in.

Comment: But actually, zerofree keeps running!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with Ubuntu 16.04 running on Hyper-v.  I desire to boot into recovery mode and run resize2fs on a partition.  I select recovery mode form the grub menu, enter the password, and get a shell.  At some point shortly after that, no matter what I'm doing (typing, reading, idle, etc) it exits the shell on its own and throws me back into the recovery menu, only now my keyboard doesn't work and I can't move through the menu.  At this point I have to reset the VM altogether.  I've been fighting this for about 4 hours now and I'm getting really, really annoyed.

Comment: Found this bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friendly-recovery/+bug/1662137?comments=all